# Keeping state between HTTP requests with python's BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, http

I have a HTTP handler derived from BaseHTTPRequestHandler

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    do_GET():
        ...
```

The problem I've been having is that I'd like to report the state of my application running in another thread.   It seems that for every request a new instance of handler is called so I can't keep my program state in MyHandler.  I could store state globally but for design reasons I don't want to do that.  Are there any other options?

Comment: Can't you use cookies to keep info about your state?

Comment: no i don't mean client state i mean there is computation being done in one thread and the the handler in another and i need computation state given to the handler

Answer (score 3):

You can use the multiprocessing module to accomplish this.  First derive a server class:

```
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    SHARED = manager.dict()
```

Then in your handler's do_GET you can do something like:

```
self.server.SHARED['foo'] = 1
```

Which should then be referable by other instance of do_GET.